# gcc define for Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c, gcc

I have a header file that is included by `*.c` and by `*.m` sources. When a C source includes the file, I'd like to skip some lines that contain Objective C stuff. Thus, I was wondering if gcc has a builtin compiler define that is active whenever it is compiling an Objective C file, something similar to the `__cplusplus` define that indicates that the compiler is currently compiling a C++ source. Is there an Objective C equivalent?

Of course, I could just `#define` my own preprocessor symbol but I'd like to know whether gcc already has an inbuilt definition for this.

Comment: Why don't you just split the header file into separate C and Obj-C header files?

Comment: I know there are dozens of alternative solutions and I know that this is bad  coding style but I'm really just interested in an answer for this question. Does the compiler define something for Objective C or not?

Comment: Google "gcc __cplusplus" and you'll find [Standard Predefined Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, gcc defines the `__OBJC__` macro whenever it is compiling an Objective C source.